# Show that $x\perp y$ for $x,y\neq 0$ implies $\{x,y\}$ is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove the following statement:

> If $x$ and $y$ are two non-zero orthogonal vectors, $x\perp y$, then the set $\{x,y\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Hint: try by contradiction: assume they are linearly dependent and see if you can get 0 for the dot product.

Answer (score 4):

Let $a x + by=0$, then $0=\langle 0,x\rangle = \langle ax + by , x \rangle = a \langle x,x \rangle +b\langle x,y \rangle=a\|x\|^2 + 0$ imply $a = 0$. 
Similar we can show b=0.

Comment: Read here to get some hints on how to write mathematics properly in this sight, lest your posts won't be read by many: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This is correct so it deserves to be upvoted.+1

Answer (score 0):

Hints: for a scalar $\;a\;$ we have

$$x=ay\iff 0\stackrel{\text{asummed}}=\langle x,y\rangle=a\langle y,y\rangle\stackrel{\div \langle y,y\rangle}\implies0=a\;\ldots$$

Comment: @ DonAntonio . thanks......

Answer (score 0):

Assume that **x**  and **y** are linearly dependent so that **x** = $\alpha$ **y** with $\alpha \ne 0$. Then the inner product is α$ ||\mathbf y||^2$ which can never be zero. So by contradiction if the vectors are orthogonal (dot product = 0) then they cannot be linearly dependent.